# Как вставлять Flash файлы

Tags: flash

Помогите. Как вставлять swf.файлы& У меня сайт почти готов. (Сделано в Publishire Office 2003.) А там такие вещи вставляются с помощью фрагмента кода HTML. У меня не получается.

HELP ME, народ. Заранее блогадарю.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для вставки, замените просто все указанные example.swf на ваши собственные пути и подправьте размеры на нужные: width и height.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="example.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <param name="play" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
    <param name="menu" value="true" />
    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
    <param name="salign" value="" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="example.fla" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="example.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
        <param name="play" value="true" />
        <param name="loop" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="window" />
        <param name="scale" value="showall" />
        <param name="menu" value="true" />
        <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
        <param name="salign" value="" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Загрузить Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
        </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

P.S. Тут определенно нужна [@Виталина](/users/22624/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).